# ingress with both rules and default backend in Google Container Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running on the Google Container Engine platform have an ingress that I would like to have a default backend service for almost all of my domains (there are quite a few, but have another, specific service for one domain on it.  Going by my understanding of the [ingress user guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) (scan for "Default Backends:" in there), the config below should work correctly.

However, it doesn't ever create the second backend. Running `kubectl describe ingress` on the ingress made and when looking at the LB in the Google console site, only the first "default" backend service is listed. Changing the default one into a rule one fixes the problem but means I have to explicitly list all of the domains I want to support.

So, I'm assuming I have a bug in the config below. If so, what is it?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: boringsites
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: boringsites
    servicePort: 80
  tls:
    - secretName: boringsites-tls
  rules:
    - host: subdomain.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: other-svc
              servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created https://gist.github.com/bprashanth/9f4533b19fd864b723ba0720a3648fa3#file-default-basic-yaml-L94 on kubernetes 1.3 and it works as expected. Perhaps you can debug backwards? Where are you running kube and what version are you using? There is a known and fixed race in 1.2 that you might be running into, especially if you updated the ingress. Also note that you need services of type=nodeport, or the ingress controller on gce will ignore the service you plugged into the reasource.

Comment: Ah! My service was still a ClusterIP. I had to replace it, and then remove the rule from the ingress and put it back (and wait a bit) for the ingress to pick up the backend again.